# Xamarin and MVVM - How can I bind a Boxview in my View to an array of Color in my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a two-dimensional array of Xamarin.Forms.Color objects in my ViewModel. I would like to bind this array to a bunch of BoxView objects in my View and set their color based on the array's contents. I know how to bind to properties like string, int or bool on a ViewModel, but if the specific value I want to bind to is a system-provided object like Color, I have no idea.

Code snippets:

ViewModel has this property that I would like to bind to:

```
public GameGrid<Color> Board;
```

View is not declared in XAML but instead via C# code. The property I'd like bound is the ColorProperty of a BoxView, like this:

```
boxView.BindingContext = _viewModel.Board[row, col];
boxView.SetBinding(BoxView.ColorProperty, ".", BindingMode.Default);
```

Given that the _viewModel.Board property is a cell in a two-dimentional array or type Color, how do I bind to it? The "." is a placeholder - I don't know what I should place there.

The GameGrid class wraps a two-dimensional array, because I figured I would need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged so I can react to individual element changes in this array later, in order to animate a game move. For completeness, its code is here:

```
public class GameGrid<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T[,] _array;

    public GameGrid(int rows, int columns)
    {
        _array = new T[rows, columns];
    }

    public T this[int a, int b]
    {
        get 
        {
            return _array[a, b];    
        }
        set
        {
            _array[a, b] = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(GameGrid<T>));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
            this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

If I change my two-dimensional array to be a simple object, eg;

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Color BindThis { get; set; }
}
public GameGrid<Wrapper> Board;
```

it is pretty trivial to bind to that property like this:

```
boxView.SetBinding(BoxView.ColorProperty, "BindThis", BindingMode.Default);
```

but that seems needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track. A single dot (`.`) is the syntax to bind to the `BindingContext` itself; not a property on the `BindingContext`, but the object that is the current `BindingContext`.

Have you tried just running the code with the `.` as the `Binding` expression?

`BoxView.Color` is of type `Xamarin.Forms.Color`, so you should be able to bind to that directly.

Comment: That is useful very to know - so that is the syntax to bind to the BindingContext itself! I just tried it out. I initialize the BoxView to a grey color, and this works great because the view starts up showing the BoxView as grey. Later on, in response to a click event, I change the color in the ViewModel to a different color - and that update doesn't appear to work - the BoxView remains grey. So it allllmosttt works!

Comment: Your INPC isn't working because you're saying that the property `GameGrid<T>` has been updated, but there isn't a property by that name. A better solution would be to have a generic event on `GameGrid<T>` to signal when it has been updated. The VM can then subscribe to that event and signal `PropertyChanged` on itself with `nameof(Board)`

Comment: That makes sense. I'm going to try that out! I'll return to mark this as the answer if that works out.